# Counting with a left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I've written this SQL (which works):

```sql
with mark_derek as (
  select rachel_id
  from chad_patrick cp
  where cp.name in ('p_mark', 'p_derek')
)
select r.id as rachel_id,
       count(md.rachel_id) as total
from rachel r
     left join mark_derek md on md.rachel_id = r.id
group by r.id;
```

The left join is important because the returned `total` column should be 0 for anything that didn't join.

I tried to condense it so that it doesn't use a CTE, by changing the `cp.name in` to `cp.name is null or cp.name in` to attempt to accommodate the left join, but it didn't work. It seemed as if the `is null` was being ignored and the row was being omitted if the left join failed.

Is there a way to fix this so that it doesn't need a subquery or CTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the CTE like this:

```
select r.id as rachel_id, count(cp.rachel_id) as total
from rachel r left join
     chad_patrick cp
     on cp.rachel_id = r.id and
        cp.name in ('p_mark', 'p_derek')
group by r.id;
```

The filtering conditions needs to go in the `on` clause.

Comment: Ok. What is the difference between putting the "in" in the join instead of the where?

Comment: @Reinderien . . . The difference between a `left join` and an `inner join`.  If the logic is in the `where`, then the `join` will be filtered to an inner join.